# CSS padding rule being ignored?

Tags: html, css

Basically when I try to define different padding amounts for the TRBL the rule gets ignored, but when I just define one padding amount the rule works.

The relevant html is as follows:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="contenttext">
    <h1>Hello.</h1>
    <p>Test text, needs more testing.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
* 
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

body
{
font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', arial, sans-serif;
}

.content
{
background: #d9d5b7;
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
}

.contenttext
{
background: #FFFFFF;
width: 750px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 500px;

padding: 25px;
}

.contenttext h1
{
font: bold 150% 'gothic century', arial, sans-serif;
color: #585858;

margin: 0px;
padding: 15px, 0px, 15px, 0px;
}

p
{
color: #707070;
}
```

Images from Chrome:

[image]

[image]

Apologies if there is something really basic I'm missing here, I'm just getting started with xhtml/css and to be honest I find it quite frustrating.

If you need the full code to determine the problem just shout and I'll upload it asap.

Comment: Another error spotted: Remove the space between `200 px` at `height: 500 px`.

Comment: *{ padding:1px; margin:1px; } is a good thing to try in a panic(Not sure its the fix here though) and stop using Dreamweaver!

Comment: Oh boy, that's not a good sign, this is all hand coded unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
padding: 15px 0;
```

no commas between values

UPDATE: also **NO** whitespaces between the numbers and `px` in style values

Comment: Apologies, this was an edit in the post as I noticed it was just one value, the chrome screenshots show the commas in correctly. I'll fix the post.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the commas between your multiple padding values.

EDIT: Ignore that for a sec, I looked at the values in chrome, gimme a couple mins.

Answer (score 2):

The screenshots seem to show that you’ve included commas between the padding values:

```
padding: 15px, 0, 15px, 0;
```

Commas aren’t allowed there.

Comment: I took to laugh when I noticed this, as I had padding elsewhere in the css without the commas. Thank you Paul, it has been a long day indeed!

Comment: @Gybe: one of those days, glad we helped spot the issue. This is one of those situations where being able to validate your code easily from your IDE can save a bunch of time.